# How to access current user with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise as well as ldap in my application to authenticate users. I have got the users model set up as well as devise. I can properly sign in and sign out users but I cannot access any information for the devise built in helper; current_user.

I want the main page of the application to show the current users name at the top of the page. I have created the column in the users table called display_name.

This is the code that I want to work:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
 <div> <%= current_user.display_name %> </div>
<% end %>
```

When I used byebug and try to access the current user it returns nil.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can access the current users information?

**Update**

I tried using:  `<% if signed_in %>`
but i still get the same error: undefined method `display_name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: try `<% if signed_in? %>` instead of `<% user_signed_in? %>`

Comment: see my update on the post.

Answer (score 1):

[`devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) documentation says:

> If your devise model is something other than User, replace "_user"
>   with "_yourmodel".

Is your model `User`? If not, you need to use the appropriate helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Which LDAP gem are you using?  `devise_ldap_authenticatable` ?

You will need to define an instance variable `@current_user` in your ApplicationController, and set it to the correct user record based on the LDAP account which authenticated.

Then, during sign-in you need to set the value of @current_user, and during sign-out you need to set it to nil.

So for sign-in and sign-out you would have to implement this in Session#create and Session#destroy

Comment: I just defined the instance variable for current_user, how to i set it during sign in and set it to nil on sign out?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes